# Content in single page or divide into components

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

Suppose i want to create a page as follow in angular with requirement:
1) Each of the section will not be reused in any other page
2) If one of the api fail, the whole page will return blank with a single error message

Which approach should i choose in inplementing? 
a) divide each section into components (with separate request on each component) and use the component in the page

b) put everything into single page (with parallel http request)

Or any other prefer method?

[image]

Comment: 'Each of the section will not be reused in any other page' nice assumption you got there

Comment: @misha130 is this a complement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since

> 1) Each of the section **will not be reused** in any other page 
>   2) **If one
>   of the api fail, the whole page will return blank** with a single error
>   message

The best way to do it would be

> Put everything into single page (with parallel http request)

That way you avoid all the parent-child component communication in case any of the requests fail, and you can handle the status of the entire page in a single place. And also since the requests are going to be sent in a parallel way, doing this won't affect the loading time of the page either.

**Note:** The only scenario where creating several child components would be still recommended is if each component has a lot of complex logic/calculations. In that case, it'd be better to split the logic and put each piece of it only where it's needed (instead of having a page with several hundreds of lines of code).

Comment: They should be separated if they do logically distinct things, regardless of the size of the code required. With rxjs and shared service patterns communication isn't a hard problem to solve, neither is having the whole page fail if one http call fails.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @bryan60. The question was made in the context of Ionic, and thus all these components are _logically_ part of the same page, so including them on the same page would not be necessarily a bad approach. So since we're in the context of a mobile app (where resources may be limited) adding an extra service and some rxjs subscriptions just for managing the communication doesn't seem to be the best way to do it if these components are not going to be reused in any other page. But yes, both ways would work just fine.